# Stop Sophos trying to update immediately after login

Tags: anti-virus, sophos

All of our corporate PCs have Sophos installed, but we're getting complaints about slow network speed and boot times from the users.

We've tracked this down to Sophos checking for updates as soon as the user logs in - the checking process eats cycles on the workstation, and the network access of 100+ PCs to check the server at the start of the day eats the bandwidth.

Is it possible to stop the Sophos auto-updating service from doing this, and make it wait to the next scheduled check time (which gets randomised over time)?

Answer (score 2):

[This blog post](http://www.myblog.bloggybloggy.com/tag/sophos-autoupdate/) talks about how you may schedule these auto-updates. The Sophos website has more info; [Google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&rlz=1C1GGLS_enUS326US326&q=schedule+sophos+autoupdate&btnG=Search) turned up plenty of pointers, too.